# Azure Function error - 'The Keys feature is not available because Authentication/Authorization is enabled for this Function App.'

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I wanted to learn about Azure Functions and so created a one from the HttpTrigger-CSharp template in the portal.

Once the Azure Function was created I see a warning message in the Keys tab indicating that 'The Keys feature is not available because Authentication/Authorization is enabled for this Function App.'

Under 'Integrate', allowed HTTP methods are 'All methods', the mode is 'Standard' and the Authorization Level is 'Function'.

Under 'Manage', the error message is displayed for Function keys and Host Keys and the function state is enabled.

In the Settings of the Functional App itself, I navigated to 'Platform Features' / 'Networking' / 'Authentication / Authorization' and App Service Authentication is Off, contrary to the error message.

Where I attempt to Test the Azure Function, I get none of the expected messages in the log.

When I click on ' Get function URL', the function URL is empty.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Hopefully I am missing something simple.

It should be noted that I can create an Azure Function from the TimerTrigger-CSharp template and it runs successfully.

Comment: I'd advice you to delete the function and create it from scratch

Comment: I deleted the function and created a new one from scratch, but unfortunately have exactly the same issue. Did your advice solve the issue for you?

Comment: Did you reuse an existing Web App Plan?

Comment: When creating the Function App I used Pay-As-You-Go, Consumption Plan, Australia Southeast and selected 'Create New' for storage.

Comment: The same problem exists at my end, so I'll guess it's some kind of Azure bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pretty big bug, you can follow this thread.

https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/1229

I encourage you to complain in that thread. Issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll keep my eye on the issues of the git repo in the future. I thought the issue was likely to be me as it was it was my first Azure Function!

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in the latest portal deployment. It has now been addressed. Please see https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/1229 for details.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, and it was a ui glitch and indeed has been resolved now as @david-ebbo mentioned.